# How to return data from OCR Detector.Processor in Google sample Android code

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, ocr, onactivityresult

In this [sample Android program](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mobile-vision-ocr/#1), the device's camera is used to perform optical character recognition through the `com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision` library.

In `visionSamples\ocr-codelab\ocr-reader-complete\app\src\main\java\com\google\android\gms\samples\vision\ocrreader\OcrDetectorProcessor.receiveDetections()` I am able to see the text that is identified using logging:

```
Log.d("OcrDetectorProcessor", "Text detected! " + item.getValue());
```

The above process is started by `OcrCaptureActivity`:

```
TextRecognizer textRecognizer.setProcessor(new OcrDetectorProcessor(mGraphicOverlay));
CameraSource mCameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(), textRecognizer)/* snip */.build();
CameraSourcePreview mPreview = (CameraSourcePreview) findViewById(R.id.preview);
mPreview.start(mCameraSource, mGraphicOverlay);
```

So we see that the above set of "stuff" is not your typical way to crank-up an activity.

**This question is about how to feed the results from the** `OcrDetectorProcessor` **back to** `OcrCaptureActivity`.

I tried adding `onActivityResult()` to `OcrCaptureActivity`, **but it does not fire:**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.v(TAG, ">>>>>>> OnActivityResult intent: " + data);
}
```

Because `OcrDetectorProcessor` is not an `Activity`, I can't simply create a new Intent and use the `setResult()` method.

There is a `OcrDetectorProcessor.release()` method, which runs at the right time (when the Android back button is pressed), but I'm not sure how to have it communicate with the parent process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally what you need to do is to save a reference to the `OcrDetectorProcessor`, then write a data retrieval method and call it from `OcrCaptureActivity`.

So make this change to your 'onCreate()':

```
//TextRecognizer textRecognizer.setProcessor(new OcrDetectorProcessor(mGraphicOverlay));
mDetectorProcessor = new OcrDetectorProcessor(mGraphicOverlay);
TextRecognizer textRecognizer.setProcessor(mDetectorProcessor);
```

Then in your `OcrDetectorProcessor` class, add a data retrieval method that returns instance variables of your choice:

```
public int[] getResults() {
    return new int[] {mFoundResults.size(), mNotFoundResults.size()};
}
```

Then add this method to `OcrCaptureActivity()`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int[] results = mDetectorProcessor.getResults();
    Log.v(TAG, "About to finish OCR.  Setting extras.");
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra("totalItemCount", results[0]);
    data.putExtra("newItemCount", results[1]);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed(); // Needs to be down here
}
```